# Cleanup for locks created using apache curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am new to Apache Curator and want to confirm few things related to distributed lock using Apache Curator:

1. I am providing lock path as "lock/unique_id" while creating instance of InterProcessMutex. 
   `InterProcessMutex dMutex = new InterProcessMutex(curatorClient, "lock/<id>");`
   Since there will be multiple locks created based on value of "id", how can I ensure old locks are deleted. Is this handled by curator? If yes, after how much time will this lock be deleted?
2. If my JVM instance is killed(which originally created the InterProcessMutex object), will it automatically delete the corresponding lock?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Curator with ZooKeeper 3.5+ then, yes, "parent" nodes of Curator recipes are created as Container ZNodes (see http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.7/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Container+Nodes) and are automatically deleted after a period where they have no child ZNodes.

Comment: I am using zookeeper 3.4.9, is there a standard solution to support deletion of old locks in this version?

Comment: You'd have to use Curator's Reaper classes for this. Unfortunately, the docs are no longer public on these but I think the Javadoc shows how to use them. See: https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/locks/ChildReaper.html

Answer (score 0):

in case still relevant :)

I am using ZooKeeper 3.4.10 , and as @Randgalt mentioned , you have to use the deprecated Reaper. an example is :

```
private void createClient(String zkConnect, int reapingThresholdMs) throws Exception {

 client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnect, new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));

    client.start();

    reaper = new Reaper(client, reapingThresholdMs);
    reaper.start();
}

public DistributedLock createLock(String lockPath) {
        String fullLockPath = checkPathAndAddPrefix(lockPath);
        reaper.addPath(fullLockPath, Reaper.Mode.REAP_UNTIL_DELETE);
        return new DistributedLock(client, fullLockPath);
    }
```